# Does PhpStorm support blueprints for projects?

Tags: phpstorm

I spend most of my time developing custom WP themes. But at the end of the day I have a "pattern" of files and layouts I use constantly and that need small amounts of editing. Is there a way to setup a blueprint with phpStorm? So every time I start a new project, I already have those files in place (folder structure).

I am not talking cloning wordpress or anything related to wordpress really. I know there are software that will let you create blueprints so that you don't have do it manually every time. Just wondering if phpStorm has that functionality. I haven't been able to find anything about it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately not.

Watch these tickets to get notified on progress (star/vote/comment):

- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-11209
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-15677
- https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-11807